# what is the best way to create a form in react native

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-native

I'm new to react native and I have a project due in 5 days.
i can't find a way to create a form and submit it in react native.
i need to save the values of the form and send them in the body of an API.
Thanks for the help !

Comment: Use some npm module for that. I would recommend checking react-hook-form

Comment: @jayzee I would just use textinputs and style them to your needs and every input holds a state that you can pass when you want to submit so onPress on the button

Comment: no need to use a form then ? @yesIamFaded

Comment: @jayzee no you dont need to use form. you just have your screen with multiple inputs that are managed by state and a button that sends the data to your api. you pass the states to a function that sends that data

Comment: Can you please send me some template because ive been trying for a while now and its not quite working...
how to save the data and that stuff
sorry if im bothering you

Answer (score 0):

Just make inputs component and get their values and a button whi call your function yo the API.

// Components

```
<TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.name = text} placeholder="name" />
<TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.email = text} placeholder="email" />
<Button title="Send" onPress={this.send} />
```

//Function

```
send(){
    // your request
    request(this.name, this.email)
}
```